# Adding coordinates to forest edge path

Tags: forest, trees

I've got:
[image]
I'd like something like:
[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={rectangle,rounded corners,draw, l sep=20pt,
    if n children=0{
        tier=terminal
    }{}}
[Initial State 
    [No Failures,edge label={node[midway,left] {$0.9994$}} [OK,green,edge label={node[midway,left] {$1$}}]]
    [Failure,edge label={node[midway,right] {$0.0006$}}
        [A,edge label={node[midway,left] {\small$5\cdot 10^{-4}$}}[OK,green,edge label={node[midway,left] {$0.95$}}]]
        [B,edge label={node[midway,right,yshift=-1.5mm,xshift=-0.4mm] {\small$8\cdot 10^{-5}$}}[OK,green,edge label={node[midway,left] {$0.9$}}]] 
        [C,edge label={node[midway,right,xshift=2mm] {\small$2\cdot 10^{-5}$}}
            [OK,green, edge label={node[midway,right,yshift=-5mm] {$0.4$}}]
            [1, edge label={node[midway,left] {$0.3$}}
                 [FAIL, red]]
            [2, edge label={node[midway,right] {$0.3$}}
                 [FAIL, red]]               
        ]
    ] 
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Has anyone got a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{special edge/.style={        edge path={
            \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
            let \noexpand\p1=(!u.parent anchor), 
            \noexpand\p2=(.child anchor) in (!u.parent anchor) -- 
            (\noexpand\x2,{\noexpand\y1-abs(\noexpand\x2-\noexpand\x1)}) 
    --   (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
        },      
}}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={rectangle,rounded corners,draw, l sep=20pt,
    if n children=0{
        tier=terminal,
    }{}}
[Initial State 
    [No Failures,edge label={node[midway,left] {$0.9994$}} [OK,green,edge label={node[midway,left] {$1$}}]]
    [Failure,edge label={node[midway,right] {$0.0006$}}
        [A,edge label={node[midway,left] {\small$5\cdot 10^{-4}$}}[OK,green,edge label={node[midway,left] {$0.95$}}]]
        [B,edge label={node[midway,right,yshift=-1.5mm,xshift=-0.4mm] {\small$8\cdot 10^{-5}$}}[OK,green,edge label={node[midway,left] {$0.9$}}]] 
        [C,edge label={node[midway,right,xshift=2mm] {\small$2\cdot 10^{-5}$}}
            [OK,special edge,green, edge label={node[pos=0,above left] {$0.4$}}]
            [1, edge label={node[midway,right] {$0.3$}}
                 [FAIL, red]]
            [2, edge label={node[midway,right] {$0.3$}}
                 [FAIL, red]]               
        ]
    ] 
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In order to get rid of the gaps, you may want to use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\forestset{special edge/.style={        edge path={
            \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
            let \noexpand\p1=(!u.parent anchor), 
            \noexpand\p2=(.child anchor) in (!u.parent anchor) -- 
            (\noexpand\x2,{\noexpand\y1-abs(\noexpand\x2-\noexpand\x1)}) 
    --   (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
        },      
}}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={rounded rectangle,draw, l sep=20pt,
    if n children=0{
        tier=terminal,
    }{}}
[Initial State 
    [No Failures,edge label={node[midway,left] {$0.9994$}} [OK,green,edge label={node[midway,left] {$1$}}]]
    [Failure,edge label={node[midway,right] {$0.0006$}}
        [A,edge label={node[midway,left] {\small$5\cdot 10^{-4}$}}[OK,green,edge label={node[midway,left] {$0.95$}}]]
        [B,edge label={node[midway,right,yshift=-1.5mm,xshift=-0.4mm] {\small$8\cdot 10^{-5}$}}[OK,green,edge label={node[midway,left] {$0.9$}}]] 
        [C,edge label={node[midway,right,xshift=2mm] {\small$2\cdot 10^{-5}$}}
            [OK,special edge,green, edge label={node[pos=0,above left] {$0.4$}}]
            [1, edge label={node[midway,right] {$0.3$}}
                 [FAIL, red]]
            [2, edge label={node[midway,right] {$0.3$}}
                 [FAIL, red]]               
        ]
    ] 
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, only that I need the child anchor shifted a bit to the left, since the edge to "1" is a bit left to u.south, could you help me with that? I tried manually offsetting the variable by a few mm, but it doesn't work...

Comment: @HorstMonika I slightly changed gears and now added a `special edge` style for that. (BTW, are the gaps at the rounded corners on purpose? If not, you may want to load `\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}` and use `rounded rectangle` instead of `rectangle,rounded corners`.)

Comment: I used your (edited) solution. Thank you very much!